# Importing ESRI:102091 Monte Mario reference system

Tags: coordinate-system, carto

I am trying to import a dataset generated by my local council (Turin, Italy).

The data appears on the map but it's slightly shifted and it doesn't match the Open Street map layer that CartoDB uses as a default.

Is there any way I can easily convert all my datasets to match CartoDB standards? By opening the .prj file I have it looks like I am using Monte Mario reference system.. This is what is says:

```python
PROJCS['Monte_Mario_Italy_1', 
    GEOGCS['GCS_Monte_Mario',
        DATUM['D_Monte_Mario', 
            SPHEROID['International_1924', 6378388.0, 297.0]], 
        PRIMEM['Greenwich', 0.0], 
        UNIT['Degree', 0.0174532925199433]], 
    PROJECTION['Transverse_Mercator'],
    PARAMETER['False_Easting', 1500000.0],       
    PARAMETER['False_Northing', 0.0], 
    PARAMETER['Central_Meridian', 9.0],
    PARAMETER['Scale_Factor', 0.9996],
    PARAMETER['Latitude_Of_Origin', 0.0], 
    UNIT['Meter', 1.0], 
    AUTHORITY['EPSG', 3003]]
```

Comment: you can find text format for diffent projection. Look at  [this site](http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/monte-mario-italy-zone-1/)

Comment: Remember to click the check mark next to the answer if it fixed your problems

Answer (score 3):

The ESRI definition of Monte Mario lacks the +towgs84 datum shift. This is the shift you encounter against the WGS84 based coordinate system that Openstreetmap uses.

Try instead `EPSG:3003 Monte Mario / Italy zone 1`

The Proj.4 definition is:

```
+proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=9 +k=0.9996 +x_0=1500000 +y_0=0 +ellps=intl +towgs84=-104.1,-49.1,-9.9,0.971,-2.917,0.714,-11.68 +units=m +no_defs
```

and the complete WKT definition:

```
PROJCS["Monte Mario / Italy zone 1",
GEOGCS["Monte Mario",
    DATUM["Monte_Mario",
        SPHEROID["International 1924",6378388,297,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","7022"]],
        TOWGS84[-104.1,-49.1,-9.9,0.971,-2.917,0.714,-11.68],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","6265"]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],
    UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","4265"]],
PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],
PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",0],
PARAMETER["central_meridian",9],
PARAMETER["scale_factor",0.9996],
PARAMETER["false_easting",1500000],
PARAMETER["false_northing",0],
UNIT["metre",1,
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],
AXIS["X",EAST],
AXIS["Y",NORTH],
AUTHORITY["EPSG","3003"]]
```

You can put that into the .prj file.

Comment: Thank you very AndreJ much, i tried and it's seems to work perfectly.

Comment: Glad to help. Think of accepting the answer: http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers since it seems to solve your matter.